# How many ways can the alphabet be rearranged so that A comes before B in a random order?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a counting problem:

> How many ways can the alphabet be rearranged so that A comes before B in a random order?

I know there are $26!$ ways for the alphabet to be arranged, but I'm not sure how to figure out the A before B part.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In half of the 26! permutations $A$ will be before $B$. So it is 26!/2.

Comment: So, I'm guessing that using the same logic, its 26!/2 for A before Z since it's a random order?  Also, is the number of ways for A to come just before B 25!?

Comment: First question yes, for every ...A...Z... permutation there is one ...Z...A... 2nd Question Yes: Here AB can be seen as one single "supercharacter".

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate the help.